How to get account details like firstname, lastname, email from user id in application insights query in azure
I am trying to access requests made by different users. I am unable to get user account details  like firstname, lastname, email regarding calls made. There are no fields as such and also not sure which field to use as user_Id field value is not useful. How can I achieve the same ?  Please help me with queries in Azure portal directly , I am not accessing this via code.
requests
| where client_CountryOrRegion !="Sample" and user_Id !=''


You should send the additional user level properties into the Application Insight TelemetryTrace under the TelemetryClient class.
Example can be seen here - https://dzimchuk.net/tracing-and-logging-with-application-insights/
